# Cannot use MockedStatic properly in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a Unit Test for the following method where a static `LoggingUtils` method is used:

```java
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<SiteDTO> findAll() {

    // code omitted     

    final boolean isDeleted = site.isDeleted();
    if (isDeleted) {
        LoggingUtils.info("Info...");
    }
    return new PageImpl<>(siteDTOList);
}
```

Here is `LoggingUtils` class and static method:

```java
public class LoggingUtils {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingUtils.class);

    public static void info(String var1) {
        String httpRequestId = getOrCreateRequestId();
        String s = "-" + httpRequestId + "- " + var1;
        log.info(s);
    }
}
```

I use the following approach, but it causes the following error on pipeline. Here is the error line in the log file:

```java
@Test
public void test() {

    // code omitted 
    
    when(demoRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(sitePage);
    

    static MockedStatic<LoggingUtils> mocked = mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class);
    Page<SiteDTO> result = siteService.findAll();

    mocked.verify(times(1), () -> LoggingUtils.info(any(), any()));
}
```

```
c.myproject.logging.util.LoggingUtils   : Drive response is empty !
```

As I have no experience to test static method in Unit Test, I think I made a mistake, but I cannot find. So, how to fix that problem? Can I mock the static method using a better approach?

Comment: Does anybody else have ever used MockedStatic?

Comment: Try to make your example minimal but complete. You receive `Drive response is empty`. We have no chance of knowing where it come from. Thus, it is hard to guess the reason of the problem. However: 1. You call `log.info` with one argument in method under thest, but verify an overload with 2 arguments. 2. You need to close MockedStatic - otherwise tests are not self-contained. 3. Reconsider your design - all log messages will come with `LoggingUtils` as source - this obscures the logs to the point of making them useless. MDC may be a better way.

Comment: Thanks, what about giving an example for mocking static methods in JUnit5 ?

Comment: Baeldung has a nice tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: Yes, I probably read it. But it does not give a verify example.